# Codeigniter HMVC modules structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm working on a content management system in Codeigniter with the Datamapper and HMVC extension. My question is, how to handle submodules.

Example: 
I want to create an User module which exists from Users, Usergroups, Rights and Modules. In codeigniter I have build it now like this:

```
Codeigniter root
    application
      modules
        Users
          models 
            user
            right
            usergroup
            module
```

Is this the right way to fix it or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have submodules in HMVC without extending the MY_router class.

You have a nice tutorial here: [HMVC: an Introduction and Application](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/)